# How to change height of owner drawn listbox dynamically in windows mobile?

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox, windows-mobile, ownerdrawn

I am trying to create owner drawn listbox on windows mobile 6.1 I have specified `LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` style while creating listbox control.  I am handling `WM_MEASUREITEM` and `WM_DRAWITEM` accordingly.

I want to change height of listbox item whenever its font changes (I change it using `WM_SETFONT` after creating control). The problem is that `WM_MEASUREITEM` message gets sent only once. I need a way to generate `WM_MEASUREITEM` message again so that I can set height of item to height of font. I have seen the article http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/controls/listview/advanced/article.php/c1013/, but it uses MFC, while I am developing this control directly using WINAPI. Some articles mention that resizing the control generates `WM_MEASUREITEM` message again. However, it is not getting generated in my case.

Please let me know is there any way to achieve this in windows mobile.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing particularly MFC in that code.  OnSetFont is, simply, handling WM_SETFONT.  MeasureItem is handling, in the MyListCtrl, the WM_MEASUREITEM sent to its parent.

As for generating a new WM_MEASUREITEM when you resize the window can't you just do a SendMessage when handling the WM_SIZE/WM_SIZING?

Comment: Thanks for the response Goz.

I tried using SendMessage directly and it did generate WM_MEASUREITEM & WM_DRAWTEM messages. In WM_MEASUREITEM handler, I changed height of the item. However, this changed height was not reflected in subsequent WM_DRAWITEM messages.

Regarding resizing the window, I don't need to resize the window. I was just trying to use it to generate WM_MEASUREITEM. Can you please suggest any other way to change the height of item?